# Selenium isDisplayed() is returning NoSuchElementException when I expect false

Tags: selenium

when my code runs and the element exists then it eleExists is set to true, but when it doesn't exist instead of being set to false I get a  NoSuchElementException.
I am wondering if this is a bug in Selenium?

```
try{

    boolean eleExists = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("Element cssSelector")).isDisplayed();
    if(eleExists)
    {
             // do stuff
    }
    else{
            // do other stuff
    }

}catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

I see for the Question:
Selenium Webdriver - using isDisplayed() in If statement is not working

the solution was to Wrap the code in a try catch, which I have done and it is working now.
but I am curious to know if this behavior is intended or not.

Comment: This is expected behavior. The element does not exist.

Comment: you're checking "isDisplayed"... that's not the same as "exists".  The element could be there, but not visible/displayed.  NoSuchElement is thrown when the element does not exist.  It's worth noting that findElements() won't throw that error, but instead return an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Web elements can have multiple states. This happens because one element can be or not on page, be invisible or enable.
A good practice to handle with this, is through selenium [waits.](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Some remarkable web elements states are:

**exists:** - The element is on DOM, but we can't say if it's enable, or visible.

**visible:** - The element is on DOM and visible, but we can't say if it's enable (if it's a button, for example, it's not possible click on it).

**clickable or enable:** - The element is fully operational

This a code example of using wait to interact with the element.

```
...
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
...
selector = (By.TAG_NAME, 'body')

# this returns the element as driver.find_element()
element = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(selector))

element.click()
```